# Add separate vlines to ggplot for each factor group (dotplot for variable importance random forest)

Tags: r, ggplot2, random-forest

I am using ggplot2 to make a dotplot of six related variable importance results from a random forest. My data (which I have already converted to long format using reshape2) look like this (my real dataset is a bit bigger):

```
Factor    Group    Value
Gender      A      0.000127
Age         A      0.000383
Informant   A     -0.000191
Gender      B     -0.000255
Age         B      0.000389
Informant   B     -0.000312
Gender      C     -0.000285
Age         C      0.000389
Informant   C     -0.000282
```

I can make the dotplot like this:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x = Value, y = Factor, colour = Group)) + geom_point()
```

here is an example of what this looks like with a different dataset:
[image: from r-bloggers.com/summarising-data-using-dot-plots]

However, what I would like is to draw a line indicating which Factors are significant for each Group. As stated on page 4 of [this guide](http://www.stanford.edu/~stephsus/R-randomforest-guide.pdf), in such datasets "*variables can be considered informative and important if their variable importance value is above the absolute value of the lowest negative-scoring variable"*.

I would like a plot which looks like the above one, whilst having individual significance lines for each Group. This code gets me close, but doesn't do separate lines for each Group. Would anyone know how to do this?  I've tried mapping the aesthetic colour to Group, but am obviously missing something.

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x = Value, y = Factor, colour = Group)) +
geom_point() +geom_vline(data=mydata, aes(xintercept=abs(min(Value)),
colour=Group))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why your code doesn't work, but something is going wrong with the way `geom_vline` is applying the functions in the `xintercept` parameter. Instead, do this operation outside of `ggplot` to create a separate data frame with the x-intercept value for each level of `Group` and feed that to `geom_vline`.

```
# Create the dotplot without the significance lines
p = ggplot(mydata, aes(x = Value, y = Factor, colour = Group)) +
           geom_point()

# Create a separate data frame with the x-intercept for each level of Group 
# (I used dplyr for this, but you can of course do this in base R, data.table, 
#  or whatever your favorite method happens to be)
library(dplyr)
signif.lines = mydata %.%
  group_by(Group) %.%
  summarise(xvalue=abs(min(Value)))

# Add significance lines to the plot using the new data frame
p + geom_vline(data=signif.lines, aes(xintercept=xvalue, colour=Group))
```

[image]