# Is behavior of geom_vline inconsistent with behavior of other ggplot geoms?

Tags: r, ggplot2

It seems like `geom_vline` does not behave "properly" with colour aesthetics when compared with other `ggplot` geoms. I'm trying to figure out whether I'm misunderstanding something about `geom_vline` or whether this is an oversight in the design of `geom_vline`.

```
# Fake data for illustration
dat=data.frame(x=rnorm(60), y=rep(LETTERS[1:3],20))
```

All of these work as expected:

```
# Density plot of x with vertical median line
ggplot(data=dat) + 
  geom_density(aes(x=x)) + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=median(x)))

# Density plot of exp(x) with vertical median line
ggplot(data=dat) + 
  geom_density(aes(x=exp(x))) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=median(exp(x))))

# Separate density plots of exp(x) for each level of y
ggplot(data=dat) + 
  geom_density(aes(x=exp(x), colour=y))
```

[image]

However, the plots below work differently. I expected the second `geom_vline` statement in the plots below to include a separate median line for each level of `y`. But in fact it just adds one line at the median of all values of `x` (as shown by the fact that it does the same thing as the first `geom_vline` statement).

```
# Separate density plots of x for each level of y
ggplot(data=dat) + 
  geom_density(aes(x=x, colour=y)) + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=median(x)), lwd=4, colour="black") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=median(x), colour=y), lwd=1)

# Density plot of x, faceted by level of y
ggplot(data=dat) + 
  geom_density(aes(x=x, colour=y)) + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=median(x)), lwd=4, colour="black") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=median(x), colour=y), lwd=1) + 
  facet_grid(. ~ y)
```

[image]

It seems like `geom_vline` is behaving differently than would be expected from the usual `ggplot` logic. For example, as shown above, I can pass a function of the data, `exp(x)`, to `geom_density` and it returns separate density plots for each level of `y` when a colour aesthetic is included. In addition, as long as there's no colour aesthetic, I can pass a function of the data, `exp(x)` or `median(exp(x))`, to `geom_vline` and it also behaves as expected. But when I try to use a colour aesthetic or faceting with `geom_vline`, it fails to provide separate median lines for each level of the `colour` variable, instead adding a single line for the median over all of the `x` values.

I know I can pass pre-summarized data to `geom_vline` to get the behavior I want (in fact, answering [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24015834/add-separate-vlines-to-ggplot-for-each-factor-group-dotplot-for-variable-import/24021725#24021725) is what raised the issues discussed here), but I'm trying to understand whether there's actually an inconsistency in the behavior of `geom_vline` relative to other `ggplot` geoms.

Am I missing something or is `geom_vline` really behaving differently than other `ggplot` geoms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"But in fact it just adds one line at the median of all values of x."

Right, you're taking the median of all values of `x`, which is just one number. In other words, `median(x)` is evaluated on the whole dataset, not for each group. You can see this same behavior with a simpler plot that uses `geom_point` rather than `geom_vline`:

```
qplot(x, median(x), color=y, data=dat)
```

[image: Value of x against median(x)]

Comment: When I saw your example, I immediately thought that I should have been using `stat_summary` with `geom="vline"`to get vertical median lines for each level of `y`, but it turns out that [this doesn't work](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/z_wHIzwSSzM), so you have to do the summarizing outside of `ggplot` and then pass the summary data frame to `geom_vline`.

Comment: That was my instinct too, and I found that same discussion. Oh well!